# import weka.jar file

Tags: java, jar, weka

I am a student at a local university in Atlanta , Georgia. I am looking for incorporating Weka.jar file to my eclipse for my class project.

I have tried  many time to incorporate the weka-3.4.jar file into our java build path in java project using Eclipse.

Each time, my program gave me  an error saying that weka.core could not be resolved from my  import statement in my java test program.

It seems very obvious that i did  missed something very important but i could not figure it out.

If you know what 's happening, i would like to seek your help, please tell me what to do in order to fix  this error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can get weka jar file from the weka file 
just go in program file => weka folder => there are 3 jar files. So you can add to your eclipse. Then,
go to your eclipse project then build path and add in libraries there,
 it works!

Comment: This approach works fine in IntelliJIDEA IDE, thanks. For command line usage, I followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt

Answer (score 0):

Do you compile and run your program using Eclipse ("Run") or do you use the command line? If you use Eclipse to run your program you should add the jar file in your project properties under "*Java Build Path*" > "*Libraries*" > "*Add external JARs...*". When using the command line, use the -jar parameter, e.g., `java -jar path_to_file/weka-3.4.jar yourprogram`