# javac: invalid flag: activation-1.1.jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar

I'm using Tomcat7 , jdk 1.7.0_55 & eclipse, when I trying to compile the entire project(Java Code) using COMMAND PROMPT, its showing Error Like 
javac: invalid flag: D:\COMPILE\lib\activation-1.1.jar.
The given below steps are followed to compile the code.

```
Step.1: dir *.java /s /b > FilesList.txt
Step.2: javac @FilesList.txt -d compiledCode -cp D:\COMPILE\lib\*.jar
```

After run the Step.2 command its showing Error.so I removed the error jar file from my lib folder & run the command but its showing same error with another jar.

Note: I Already have ANT build.xml but I want to compile the project through COMMAND PROMPT.

Comment: The `lib*.jar` gets expanded by the command shell. You need to avoid that. The argument to `-cp` is a single path list. Multiple files can be separated by ":" (maybe ; on Windows)

Comment: thank you very ,its working for me.In Windows                  ***** -cp "D:\COMPILE\lib\*.;" *****

Answer (score 10):

The `lib*.jar` gets expanded by the command shell. You need to avoid that by using quotes.

```
***** -cp "D:\COMPILE\lib\*" *****
```

The argument to `-cp` is a single path list (like `$PATH`, not multiple arguments with one path each). Multiple files can be separated by `:` (or `;` on Windows)

Comment: This saved me a lot of time and research, so thank you.