# Include jar to a jar

Tags: java, apache, jar, classpath, executable-jar

I want to make the jar file for my java project. My project requires apacheTika.jar jar file to be added. How can I make the jar file including apacheTika.jar and how can I run it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include jar files with java file and compile in command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt)

Comment: Start with [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) and [Working with Manifest Files: The Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) and [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the manifest file which is used to create the jar file as follows :
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: main class name
Class-path: add location of jar files