# How to identify the dependent libraries I need

Tags: java, eclipse, wolframalpha

I am building a little something in Java that uses Wolfram|Alpha to come up with integrals.  I downloaded the [Wolfram API](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/) and it comes with a sample program that you can use to figure stuff out.  [Here's that at GitHub](https://github.com/aeurielesn/wolfram-alpha-java-binding/blob/master/SampleProgram/AlphaAPISample.java).

There's a portion in the comments that says:

```
 * To compile or run this program you will need the following dependent 
 * libraries on your classpath (including WolframAlpha.jar, of course):
 * 
 *     commons-codec-1.3.jar
 *     httpclient-4.0.1.jar
 *     httpcore-4.0.1.jar
 *     commons-logging.jar
```

... and I have no idea how to do this.  I'm using this project as a way to learn Java, so I am skipping a bunch of sleep-inducing fundamentals.

Are these libraries available in the vanilla Java install, or do I have to go fetch them from elsewhere?  I want to avoid loading up my system with redundant stuff.

When I try to run the script without loading these libraries it ends in an error, predictably.  Here's the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SocketFactory
    at com.wolfram.alpha.net.HttpProviderFactory.getDefaultHttpProvider(HttpProviderFactory.java:18)
    at com.wolfram.alpha.WAEngine.<init>(WAEngine.java:36)
    at simpleSample.main(simpleSample.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

I am using Eclipse as my IDE.  I don't think it matters here, but it might.

Comment: @Jens I agree that this problem has been addressed elsewhere.  Unfortunately it does not appear to be a duplicate as you marked it.

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt) to get you started.  You can also look into using a Maven project to handle your dependencies.

Comment: "I am skipping a bunch of sleep-inducing fundamentals", but now those sleep inducing fundamentals are giving you a headache. Maybe you should start by invoking `java -h` and have a look at the `-classpath` option.

Comment: From the readme of the project you linked - *These libraries are widely available on the Internet. You can probably
use other version numbers than these, although these are the versions
I used.* Yet another sleep-inducing fundamentals - Read a readme.

Comment: I find it ironic that multiple people are responding that I am not doing my due diligence reading many thousands of pages of documentation when they themselves cannot read a full question.  Namely this: "Are these libraries available in the vanilla Java install, or do I have to go fetch them from elsewhere? I want to avoid loading up my system with redundant stuff."  Please take into account that I am attempting to learn, not just spam my computer with whatever makes my errors go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dimplex has already answered. These are releases of several Apache projects. Next time you meet these problems, try:

**Google**:

Like:

- [Google commons-codec-1.3.jar](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&site=&source=hp&q=commons-codec-1.3.jar&btnG=Search&oq=&gs_l=)
- [Google httpclient-4.0.1.jar](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&site=&source=hp&q=httpclient-4.0.1.jar&btnG=Search&oq=&gs_l=)
- [Google httpcore-4.0.1.jar](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&site=&source=hp&q=httpcore-4.0.1.jar&btnG=Search&oq=&gs_l=)
- [Google commons-logging.jar](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&site=&source=hp&q=commons-logging.jar&btnG=Search&oq=&gs_l=)

The first result for EVERY search above is a couple clicks away from the download you're looking for.

**Maven Central Search**:

http://search.maven.org

(I'm not copying every link, just search for the Jar file names.)

This one is even more direct, but I'd recommend the Google way, as you can get a glimpse of the project page.

Comment: I know I could google and install every time I run into a problem.  If you read my question you would see this passage: "Are these libraries available in the vanilla Java install, or do I have to go fetch them from elsewhere? I want to avoid loading up my system with redundant stuff."  Thank you for your effort, though.

Comment: @n8. "Are these libraries available in the vanilla Java install, or do I have to go fetch them from elsewhere?". "These are releases of several Apache projects" answers that as a "No", and the rest of the answer tells you where that "elsewhere" is to "fetch" them. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is in assuming that I know things.  I didn't know that Java wouldn't include those libraries, that's why I asked if they were included. Sure, it stands to reason that Java wouldn't necessarily include Apache libraries in their vanilla install, but I don't know that.  So instead of making uninformed decisions, I ask the question.  Thank you for answering comprehensively, but I really just needed a "no, what you need must be downloaded."

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade the `httpclient.jar` to version 4.1.
As you can see in the [javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory.html) theses class available from this version

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

These are all (old) Apache Software Foundation libraries. The download locations are as follows:

[commons-codec-1.3.jar](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/codec/binaries/)

[httpclient-4.0.1.jar](http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/)

[commons-logging.jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi)

[httpcore-4.0.1.jar](http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpcomponents/httpcore/binary/)

Comment: I'll end up doing this if I have to, but this does not address my question.  I already have a lot of libraries, I don't want to add a bunch of redundant ones if I can help it.