# How to include jar file to java classpath in same folder

Tags: java, windows, jar, apache-fop

I am trying to include an apache fop jar file to a java classpath. The Java file has to include some fop stuff like below:

```
import org.apache.fop.apps.Driver;
import org.apache.fop.apps.Options;
```

And all files I have is fop.jar and FOPWrapper.java. When I try to compile with the following line: `javac -cp ".;*.jar" FOPWrapper.java` I still get compiler errors.

```
FOPWrapper.java:1: error: package org.apache.fop.apps does not exist
import org.apache.fop.apps.Driver;
                      ^
FOPWrapper.java:2: error: package org.apache.fop.apps does not exist
import org.apache.fop.apps.Options;
```

How am I then supposed to include the jar file so that it compiles?

Comment: Did you try with the full names of the jars?

Comment: in your -cp option, please try giving full path of your jar files.

Comment: Possibly this link can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt

Comment: Besides Shriram's general advice, I would recommend checking whether the version of FOP your code was made for matches the one of the jars you are trying to use (the use of the `Driver` class makes me think your code refers to FOP 0.20.5 which is **really** old; the current version is 2.0 and was released in June 2015).