# How do I add a library to java? I dont use any IDE, I use only the command prompt

Tags: java, github

So I am not familiar with adding new libraries to java. I downloaded a library from GitHub and I got a zip file.

I have extracted the contents but I'm lost. I dont know where and how I should add this library.

I dont use any IDE. I use the command prompt on windows 8. I use notepad to type my code

I have done my research for the last 2 hours but all of them are for some IDE and the ones that I found other than those didnt help.

I read about -classpath but I'll have to set the path every time I have a new library?? (I'm still confused)

Please tell me how to add this library. Thank you!

Comment: Simple: use an IDE.

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt
And of course start using an IDE ( Eclipse , Intelij etc ) it will increase your productivity and make your life easier ;)

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Yes I have installed maven. I have got 3 jar files and a bunch of other files with it when I ran "maven clean package" So If I copy those jar files to lib folder i'm done?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Its very confusing :/ I ran "maven clean package" on the folder that I extracted from that zip file...Am I doing it wrong? Should I create my java program and then run the command on that ??

Comment: @MrX: to use a jar with a maven project, add the jar as a dependency in your pom.xml. There is no lib folder. And notepad is about the worst editor ever.

Comment: @NathanHughes I know as people stick to easy access ready baked 1 click codes through IDE's, I prefer notepad over them so I have to type everything I'm doing and when I start to debug, Hell breaks loose when there's 500+ lines of code. But in the process I think like a machine. It definitely helps me as I'm learning java myself.

Comment: @MrX I think your approach is the right one. If you're relative new to Java, using an IDE is a good way to ensure that you _never_ really understand why you have the problems you face, and if you're ever faced with a problem your IDE can't solve, you'll be stuck. IDEs have their place, of course, but as learning tools they're terrible.

Comment: @KevinBoone Thanks man  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose I have two Java libraries packaged as jar files: `foo.jar` and `bar.jar`

The `foo.jar` contains the class `Foo.class` and the `bar.jar` contains the class `Bar.class`.

Now I am writing a piece of code in which I use both `Foo` and `Bar`.

```
package my.work;

public class TestDrive {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Foo foo = new Foo();
      Bar bar = new Bar();
      System.out.println("Hello, " + foo + " and " + bar);
   }
}
```

In order to compile `TestDrive.java` I need to know where both dependencies are located. Most likely I put them in my libs folder

```
+-project
|   +---src
|   |    +--TestDrive.java
|   +---libs
|   |    +--foo.jar
|   |    +--bar.jar
|   +---build
|   |    + my
|   |    |   +-- work 
|   |    |   |    +--TestDrive.class //once I compile it with javac
```

Then I would need to do something like

```
javac -classpath libs/foo.jar:libs/bar.jar -d build -sourcepath src src/TestDrive.java
```

So, to answer your question, yes, you need to put all your libraries in the classpath.

There are, of course, other ways to do this.

Comment: Thank you! You gave me a clear picture on the problem. I guess I'll have to take the long way if I am sticking to the command prompt.

Comment: This is the standard way to run java applications. Even IDE is doing the same thing from behind. If you don't want to type so long for your compilation and execution, try using bat files.

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo I'm stuck bud. I compiled my one liner but I am unable to run the program with -cp. It gives me an error saying it cant find or load the class file.

Answer (score 0):

> I read about -classpath but I'll have to set the path every time I have a new library?? (I'm still confused)

No.
**You have to set it every time you run your program!**

So you either create a script to run your program, or set it thru the `MANIFEST.MF` file of your program's main `JAR`...

See:

- [`java`/`javaw` arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)
- [Manifest files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)

Comment: I have got 3 jar files and a bunch of other files with it when I ran "maven clean package" So If I copy those jar files to lib folder i'm done?

Comment: What is the "lib folder"?

Comment: The library folder thats in the Jdk.

Comment: Do not put files into the `JDK`'s folders! What the others meant was probably a folder in your project, that `IDE`s and other tools usually create to hold your `JAR` files in a single place...

Comment: Oh!! I was thinking of putting them there. Is there a way without getting into the IDE's? I really wanna keep going with the command prompt until I'm familiar with all the libraries, as IDE's mess it up by auto filling and making everything easy for me.

Comment: I would use `ant` (or some other building tool) to make the compilation, packaging, etc process automated.

Answer (score 0):

Set an Environment variable **`CLASSPATH`** in **`System Properties`**--> **`Advanced`** --> **`Environment Variables`**

For example if you have multiple jar files, copy them to a dir in **`C:\LIBS\`** and set classpath value as **`C:\LIBS\*;.`**

If you want for specific jar files only  set it as, **`C:\LIBS\jar1.jar;C:\LIBS\jar2.jar;.`**

Open new command prompt and it should work and is permanent

**`NOTE` : This impacts all the instances of command prompts opened further**

Comment: "This impacts all the instances of command prompts opened further" This is what I was concerned about. If I do this, will the way I run and compile all the programs change ?

Comment: This CLASSPATH will be used by all the programs i.e impacted by javac and java commands when used in command line

Comment: "To run it successfully you need to go back to directory  C:\project and now run
C:\project>java testing.Test"

This I found here about classpath http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html#ixzz4ugzTNDNi

So I was thinking it would change the way i run programs and didnt wanna complicate things. I simply do " java program.java" and javac program.

Comment: The . ( dot or period ) at the end of classpath specifies, current working directory and you can give your build output dir like C:\Project replacing the . (dot)

Comment: Hmmm I get it! Thanks for helping! :D I have to do more research on this now.