# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when compiling jar

Tags: java, maven, google-vision

Good day to all!
I work with google vision API and when I run my program in the IntelliJ Idea, it works great, but when I compile a jar file, it gives an error when processing photos

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;CLjava/lang/Object;)V
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.validateName(Metadata.java:629)
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.<init>(Metadata.java:637)
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.<init>(Metadata.java:567)
        at io.grpc.Metadata$AsciiKey.<init>(Metadata.java:742)
        at io.grpc.Metadata$AsciiKey.<init>(Metadata.java:737)
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.of(Metadata.java:593)
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.of(Metadata.java:589)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor.<init>(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:60)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:212)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:185)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:177)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:160)
        at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.stub.GrpcImageAnnotatorStub.create(GrpcImageAnnotatorStub.java:114)
        at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.stub.ImageAnnotatorStubSettings.createStub(ImageAnnotatorStubSettings.java:151)
        at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.<init>(ImageAnnotatorClient.java:136)
        at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.create(ImageAnnotatorClient.java:117)
        at allClasses.GoogleAPI.detectText(GoogleAPI.java:26)
        at allClasses.MainClass.addMarkingPhoto(MainClass.java:129)
        at allClasses.MainClass.dir(MainClass.java:95)
        at allClasses.MainClass.dir(MainClass.java:86)
        at allClasses.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:50)
```

I read that this may be due to dependencies, but in maven I am new to and can not understand why it works in intellij and does not work when creating a jar file

My pom :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <poi.version>3.15</poi.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev110-1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>28.2-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mailjet</groupId>
            <artifactId>mailjet-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-vision</artifactId>
            <version>1.84.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

I deleted the manifest and inserted this:

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>allClasses.MainClass</mainClass>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

but nothing has changed

What could be the problem? 
Why code works in intellij and don't work after creating jar file?

Comment: Please add the stacktrace as text and not as an image.

Comment: Review the maven dependency hierarchy to see if any of the dependencies are overriding the main dependency which has "com.google.common"

Comment: @Lino  sorry , i'm edited post

Comment: @reedb89 I only see com.google.api: api-common: 1.8.1 and
com.google.api.grpc: photo-google-common-protos: 1.16.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just create jar in eclipse =)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you refer to a precise MANIFEST file, it would be useful to know what is written inside it because, as I think you know, inside the MANIFEST file there are both startup class and the list of dependencies and their location.
The POM file does not explicitly construct a "jar-with-dependency", therefore I would assume that the package you have built does not contain the necessary dependencies to use it

As a result, you have two choices:

1) create an "all-in-one" package, that contains all the dependencies necessary for its use, via maven plugin, replacing your "maven-jar-plugin" with "maven-assembly-plugin":

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>{full qualified name of main class}</mainClass>      
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

2) referencing the external dependencies via the parameter -Djava.library.path, -cp or similar

Comment: My manifest : 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: allClasses.MainClass

I added what you wrote above instead of maven-jar-plugin but the error remained

Comment: @Zeo ok, my suggestion remains. your manifest is useless, delete it and let generate it via maven. pay attention that in this way you'll find 2 jar files in your target folder: 1 "original" and 1 "with-dependencies"; obvs you have to run the big one !

Answer (score 0):

When you compile the jar file you would need to package the required dependency with jar file. You can try to explore following configuration. What it does is that it adds required dependency with jar itself and when you try to run the jar it finds all the dependency with jar itself. Here `api-all` is dependency which I would like to include with jar itself. Which has maven dependency

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>




    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.your.package</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Export-Package>com.your.package.*;org.apache.commons.beanutils.*</Export-Package>
                        <Embed-Dependency>api-all,commons-pool,mina-core,antlr</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                        <DynamicImport-Package>
                            org.dom4j, org.dom4j.io, org.jdom, org.jdom.input
                        </DynamicImport-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            !org.dom4j.*, !org.xmlpull.v1, !sun.net.util, *
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Alternatively you try to provide classpath to dependent jar in command line itself using `java -cp .:<file_1_name>.jar:<file_2_name>.jar <prog_name>`

Further reading [How to include jar files with java file and compile in command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt)