# how to use lwjgl in my project without an IDE

Tags: java, jar, compilation, ide

i have been using ide and i needed to know how dose someone uses other libs that are not on the primary installation, like "lightweight java game library" how do u compile the e.g: Main.java and the openGl that how do i use them how to set them up without an IDE

Comment: Please be specific about your question, provide what have you tried already for the same.

Answer (score 0):

One method you could follow is, If you have maven,convert your project as maven and add all the atrifactIds of libs/jars you want to compile with your code in pom.xml.Then you can use "mvn clean install" from your machine.

Comment: yeah but how can i do it with just the jdk and the lwjgl files without anything else

Comment: You can include your jar files in the "javac" command using the "-cp" option.

javac -cp ".:/home/path/mail.jar:/home/path/servlet.jar;" MyJavaFile.java
Instead of "-cp" you could also use "-classpath"

javac -classpath ".:/home/path/mail.jar:/home/path/servlet.jar:" MyJavaFile.java                                                                                           Hope this might help u..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt