# How do you compile files with multiple dependencies (imports and .jar files)?

Tags: java, terminal

I have the following directory structure:

[image]

I'm having trouble compiling the source files in the 'models' package, which rely on all other files in packages src as well as the .jar file in lib. How would I write the classpath command to compile these model files (on mac)?

```
joseph@Josephs-MacBook-Pro models % javac -cp ".:.." NeuralNetworkMultiClass.java
../utils/Metrics.java:4: error: package org.knowm.xchart.style does not exist
import org.knowm.xchart.style.AxesChartStyler;
                             ^
../utils/Metrics.java:5: error: package org.knowm.xchart.style does not exist
import org.knowm.xchart.style.Styler;
                             ^
../utils/Metrics.java:6: error: package org.knowm.xchart.style.markers does not exist
import org.knowm.xchart.style.markers.SeriesMarkers;
                                     ^
../utils/Metrics.java:3: error: package org.knowm.xchart does not exist
import org.knowm.xchart.*;
^
../utils/Metrics.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        XYChart chart = new XYChartBuilder()
        ^
  symbol:   class XYChart
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        XYChart chart = new XYChartBuilder()
                            ^
  symbol:   class XYChartBuilder
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
        XYSeries series = chart.addSeries(seriesName, xData, yData);
        ^
  symbol:   class XYSeries
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        series.setMarker(SeriesMarkers.NONE);
                         ^
  symbol:   variable SeriesMarkers
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
        new SwingWrapper<>(chart).displayChart();
            ^
  symbol:   class SwingWrapper
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList<XYChart> charts = new ArrayList<>();
                  ^
  symbol:   class XYChart
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
        XYChart chart = new XYChartBuilder()
        ^
  symbol:   class XYChart
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
        XYChart chart = new XYChartBuilder()
                            ^
  symbol:   class XYChartBuilder
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
        XYSeries costA1 = chart.addSeries("Alpha = 1", xData, ySeries[0]);
        ^
  symbol:   class XYSeries
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
        XYSeries costA2 = chart.addSeries("Alpha = 0.1" , xData, ySeries[1]);
        ^
  symbol:   class XYSeries
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
        XYSeries costA3 = chart.addSeries("Alpha = 0.01", xData, ySeries[2]);
        ^
  symbol:   class XYSeries
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
        costA1.setMarker(SeriesMarkers.NONE);
                         ^
  symbol:   variable SeriesMarkers
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
        costA2.setMarker(SeriesMarkers.NONE);
                         ^
  symbol:   variable SeriesMarkers
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
        costA3.setMarker(SeriesMarkers.NONE);
                         ^
  symbol:   variable SeriesMarkers
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
        new SwingWrapper<>(charts).displayChartMatrix();
            ^
  symbol:   class SwingWrapper
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList<XYChart> charts = new ArrayList<>();
                  ^
  symbol:   class XYChart
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
            XYChart chart = new XYChartBuilder()
            ^
  symbol:   class XYChart
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
            XYChart chart = new XYChartBuilder()
                                ^
  symbol:   class XYChartBuilder
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:123: error: cannot find symbol
            XYSeries cost = chart.addSeries("training", xData, ySeries[i]);
            ^
  symbol:   class XYSeries
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
            XYSeries recall = chart.addSeries("validation", xData, ySeries[i + 1]);
            ^
  symbol:   class XYSeries
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:125: error: cannot find symbol
            cost.setMarker(SeriesMarkers.NONE);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable SeriesMarkers
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:126: error: cannot find symbol
            recall.setMarker(SeriesMarkers.NONE);
                             ^
  symbol:   variable SeriesMarkers
  location: class Metrics
../utils/Metrics.java:131: error: cannot find symbol
        new SwingWrapper<>(charts).displayChartMatrix();
            ^
  symbol:   class SwingWrapper
  location: class Metrics
27 errors
```

Comment: There, sorry, it's not very readable. It's referring to xchart

Answer (score 1):

You're running the command from `projectDir/src/models` but `NeuralNetworkMultiClass.java` depends on other packages as well.

You could run the java compiler from `projectDir` and place all compiled class files inside `out`:

```
javac -cp "src:lib/*" -d out src/*/*.java
```

Then if you, for example, want to run `NeuralNetworkMultiClass`, you do it from `projectDir` like so:

```
java -cp "out:lib/*" models.NeuralNetworkMultiClass
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9396410/6367213) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/219801/6367213) on platform specifics when specifying a list of files/folders to the `-cp` flag.

Comment: Thank you for this, what location in my file directory would I have to execute this from?

Comment: I still seem to get the same error

Comment: @JAdamson Now it should work! :) Try swapping `:` with `;` if you still have issues.

Comment: No luck unfortunately, would restructuring the directory do any good?

Comment: The error message I get is concerning a .jar file dependency outside of the src file. I need to compile all packages and the .jar file for it to work I think

Comment: Should I move the lib file (containing the .jar file) into the source directory?

Comment: It compiles, however, I now get this error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: models/NeuralNetworkMultiClass (wrong name: NeuralNetworkMultiClass)`

Comment: @JAdamson What's the name of the class that you would like to run once compiled (the one that contains the  `main` method)?

Comment: NeuralNetworkMultiClass.java and KNNMultiClass.java

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. You really don't know how much you have helped me