# compile and run java with jar files

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm trying to compile a java file that uses multiple jar files as imports.
the command that I have used to compile my code :

```
javac -cp jackson-databind-2.12.1.jar:jackson-core-2.12.1.jar:jackson-annotations-2.12.1.jar TestRunner.java
```

as a result two .class files are created : TestRunner.class and TestRunner$1.class

then I run the command :

```
java TestRunner
```

but it throws an error that says:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class TestRunner Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference
```

I have included all the required libraries in the javac command, tested it with the IDE and it works fine.
I have tried other versions of the jackson library but I'm stuck with the same error.

Comment: add -cp option to java cmd like javac

Comment: @MarcStroebel it gives me an error : Could not find or load main class TestRunner Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestRunner

Comment: Please check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt/61969540#61969540

Comment: add the folder containing the compiled class files also to cp option

Comment: @pratap yes I have tried the same, but same error

Comment: @MarcStroebel, thanks it worked now, i have changed in the command by adding the folder containing the compiled class final : java -cp .:jackson-databind-2.12.1.jar:jackson-core-2.12.1.jar:jackson-annotations-2.12.1.jar TestRunner

Comment: @MarcStroebel added your precision to my answer, forgot about that (it's been quite a long time since I have to write a classpath by hand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the classpath when running your code, by using the same `-cp` args that you used when compiling, plus the folder where your compiled class is in.

In your cas that would mean something like `java -cp .:jackson-databind-2.12.1.jar:jackson-core-2.12.1.jar:jackson-annotations-2.12.1.jar TestRunner`

The libs you specified are not included in the `.class` files generated, so Java still needs them to understand how to call the code that's not coming from your class file.

Comment: when running :  java -cp jackson-databind-2.12.1.jar:jackson-core-2.12.1.jar:jackson-annotations-2.12.1.jar TestRunner , gives me an error : Error: Could not find or load main class TestRunner
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestRunner

Comment: @AhmedFerjani I've edited my answer to include the fact that you should add your compiled class also