# import jar file into my hello world console application

Tags: java, jar

I understand Maven is used to manage libs, but I wanted to do a simple example I thought will work  . But I am stuck with though I spent few hours searching and trying out. This bothers me a lot, before give up, I post here if anyone can help.

**What I want to do:**
I have User.java and Main.java in its own folder.
I want to build User and make it Jar.
And I want to use User.jar in my Main.java application.

**My setup:**
~/User/User.java
~/Main/Main.java

*User.java*

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    int idx;
}
```

*Main.java*

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User();
        System.out.println(user);
    }
}
```

**What I tried:**

`javac User.java`

`jar cf User.jar User.class`

copied User.jar file to Main folder

`javac -cp User.jar Main.java`

`java Main`

gives error

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: User
at Main.main (Main.java:5)**

I think giving class path to jar will fix

`Java -cp User.jar Main`

but this also gives error

**Error: Could not find or load main class Main
both give error**

what's problem and fix?

Comment: @Blednov,@g00se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should properly package your classes, but:

```
goose@t410:/tmp$ javac Main.java User.java 
goose@t410:/tmp$ jar cfe user.jar Main  Main.class User.class 
goose@t410:/tmp$ java -jar user.jar
User@4e0e2f2a
```

Comment: I learned cfe option and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your files are storing in a different packages,

> ~/User/User.java ~/Main/Main.java

and you have no `import` in your Main.java.

By default the visibility is package private level.

Comment: I look into package, import keywords once again and practiced files applying them. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find previous thread that helps.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt#comment11870389_9395207)

Reading and trying them out in my development environment which is Win 11, I found argument expression to -cp, classpath is OS depedent.

I didn't quite make it work as I wanted but I should move on.