# How do I get a JAR file in the current directory in the class path for a Java execution?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, classpath

I have a class file `Main.class` which needs a JAR file `abc.jar` to run.

Both files are in the same directory. Now I try to run the class file with

```
java -cp "." Main
```

but I get a `java.lang/NoClassDefFoundError`.

I thought `-cp "."` tells the classpath to include the current directory, but somehow it doesn't.

How do I get this JAR file in the current directory on the class path?

Comment: This thread may help you to figure out the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt

Comment: @patrinox Thanks. This got me to the solution: I forgot that the JAR _itself_ needs to be in the `CLASSPATH` property, not only the _directory_ containing the JAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [patrinox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11988137/patrinox)' comment I figured it out:

The JAR *itself* needs to be in the CLASSPATH property, not only the *directory* containing the JAR. Therefore the command line has to read:

```
java -cp ".:./abc.jar" Main
```