# Compile with Asterik-Java a ".java" file

Tags: java, compilation, classpath

I am trying to compile a file, but its fails because of the Imports.

```
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiServer;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.MappingStrategy;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.ClassNameMappingStrategy;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.DefaultAgiServer;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiServerThread;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class AgiServidor
{
    private static final Logger log;
    private AgiServerThread agiServerThread;
    private DefaultAgiServer agiServer;
    
   static {
        log = Logger.getLogger((Class)AgiServidor.class);
    }
    
   public void start() throws Exception {
        try {
            final ClassNameMappingStrategy cnms = new ClassNameMappingStrategy(false);
            (this.agiServer = new DefaultAgiServer((MappingStrategy)cnms)).setPoolSize(100);
            this.agiServer.setMaximumPoolSize(1800);
            final AgiServerThread agiServerThread = new AgiServerThread((AgiServer)this.agiServer);
            agiServerThread.setDaemon(false);
            agiServerThread.startup();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            AgiServidor.log.error((Object)"Startup failed in MBean AgiMBean -- attempting to continue", (Throwable)ex);
        }
    }
    
   public void stop() throws Exception {
        if (this.agiServerThread != null && this != null) {
            this.agiServer.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

I investigated and I must use the library "Asterik-Java" I downloaded it but I don't know where to put it, I use the path to the downloads folder and followed the path to the file.

`javac -cp C:\Users\Juan\Downloads\asterisk-java-2.0.3.jar C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\dbd\AgiServidor.java`

this is the error that i got

```
C:\Users\Juan>javac -cp C:\Users\Juan\Downloads\asterisk-java-2.0.3.jar C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\dbd\AgiServidor.java
C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\dbd\AgiServidor.java:12: error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
                       ^
C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\dbd\AgiServidor.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    private static final Logger log;
                         ^
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class AgiServidor
C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\dbd\AgiServidor.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        log = Logger.getLogger((Class)AgiServidor.class);
              ^
  symbol:   variable Logger
  location: class AgiServidor
3 errors
```

looks like i need another library, is it normal? what i am doing bad.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the asteriskjava library, you're also using the apache log4j library. If you include that jar file in your javac command, that should fix it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt) answer for more details and other ways to include jar files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).