# Error: package org.jsoup does not exist with import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jsoup

I've downloaded the Jsoup Java library for use in VS Code. I've clicked Referenced Libraries and added the JAR file there. I created this class to see if the imports work:

```java
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class n {
}
```

When I tried to compile it, I got this error:

```
javac n.java
n.java:1: error: package org.jsoup does not exist
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and look for some classes, I can see their implementations and all. Why would it not be able to find the package? I already tried compiling with `java -cp .:"jsoup-1.17.2.jar" n.java`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you looked at this: [How to include jar files with java file and compile in command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt#:~:text=You%20can%20include%20your%20jar,the%20%22%2Dcp%22%20option.&text=You%20could%20including%20the%20jars,environment%20variable%20%22CLASSPATH%22%20correctly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Step By Step Guide For a PoC JSoup + VSCode Java Project

Based on your input I am not sure what went wrong on your setup, but here is how I made a working PoC Project in VSCode using JDK 11.

#### Download JSoup Jar

I assume you already did it. I downloaded [JSoup 1.17.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.17.2) from [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com).

Put it in `lib` directory (optional, but a good practice to separate jars from code).

#### Create a Sample Java Class

```java
package com.github.tcsizmadia.jsoupsandbox;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // a simple HTML document
        final var sampleHtml = "<html>\n" +
                "<head>\n" +
                "    <title>Sample HTML</title>\n" +
                "</head>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "    <h1>Hello World!</h1>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>\n";

        // parse the HTML
        var doc = Jsoup.parse(sampleHtml);
        System.out.println("The sample HTML's Title: " + doc.title());
    }
}
```

Save it in the corresponding directory tree: `com/github/tcsizmadia/jsoupsandbox` (feel free to rename packages).

#### Compile the Java Class

```bash
javac -cp lib/jsoup-1.17.2.jar com/github/tcsizmadia/jsoupsandbox/Main.java
```

Your directory tree should look like this:

```
├── com
│   └── github
│       └── tcsizmadia
│           └── jsoupsandbox
│               ├── Main.class
│               └── Main.java
└── lib
    └── jsoup-1.17.2.jar
```

#### Run the Compiled Java Class

```bash
java -cp .:lib/jsoup-1.17.2.jar com.github.tcsizmadia.jsoupsandbox.Main
```

Result:

```
The sample HTML's Title: Sample HTML
```

Please try these steps on your environment and let us know which step failed so we can narrow down the error.

Comment: Thanks, I copied your class and created a java project. I tried to compile it, and it didn't work, but after I did it as you explained, now it worked. Using: `javac -cp lib/jsoup-1.17.2.jar src/test/jsoup/lib/App.java` and then `java -cp lib/jsoup-1.17.2.jar src/test/jsoup/lib/App.java`

Comment: Fantastic news - Congratulations! As you see coping with libraries and building your code this way is not so satisfying. I suggest you use a decent build tool like Maven or Gradle to handle your dependencies and builds. Good luck on your journey as a Java Developer!