# Classifying a new image in Weka

Tags: java, weka, image-recognition

I've done the classification of images in imageJ, using the Trainable Weka Segmentation plugin, and have gotten an `arff` file. The purpose is to recognize whether a specific object is in the image or not so I have two classes; the object and the not-object.

How do I in Java use this file to classify a new image, see if the object is in the image?  Is it even possible to do?

Comment: An arff file is a file with feature data, you need to serialize your trained model, then you can use it from Java or from the CLI.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Josep Valls menioned the .arff File is just your feature Data (what your classifying algorithm uses as training/test data).

Here you have a topic about using weka in Java:
[import weka.jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042315/import-weka-jar-file)

Here is an additional tutorial:
https://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code

After that you have 2 options:

> 1:  Serialize your model and import it into your java code: https://weka.wikispaces.com/Serialization as @Josep Valls mentioned
>
> 2: loading only the .arff file and retrain your model with the (i guess allready optimized) parameters you used before.

Answer (score 0):

The [Trainable Weka Segmentation plugin](http://imagej.net/Trainable_Weka_Segmentation) allows you to save your classifying algorithm as Weka, into a `.model` file. Just **click on "Save classifier" instead of "Save data"**. Later you can apply that model to new images by clicking on "Apply classifier".